# Is there an easy way to load a related entity from an entity?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a content entity that references another entity, ie:

```
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);

  $fields['other_entity_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Other Entity'))
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'other_entity')
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'options_select',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

Is there an easy way for me to load the other entity from the entity that references it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the entity field property. ie:

```
public function getOtherEntity()
{
  return $this->get('other_entity_id')->entity;
}
```

Comment: Maybe simple, but keep forgetting I can do this, figured other people might be doing so too.

Comment: See also http://wizzlern.nl/drupal/drupal-8-entity-cheat-sheet